# Using LaunchKernels to launch kernels with lower priorities

Tags: kernel-startup

On windows the kernels launched with `LaunchKernels` are starred with "Below Normal" priority.

**Is there a way to start them with even lower priority (eg. "Idle")?**

I'm doing some intensive numerical analysis on my computer, which becomes really unresposive while the analysis is running. If I manually lower the priority of the kernels (eg from [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)) then I'm able to work normally. But manually finding the processes every 10 minutes becomes tedious. 
Of course I could just launch fewer kernels than I have cores, but that seems inelegant.

Bonus points for a cross-platform solution:)

Comment: Does the "Run kernels at a lower process priority" checkbox in the preferences not do what you need?

Comment: @acl I already have this checked. I would need a "Run kernels at idle process priority" checkbox:)

Comment: Couldn't you not just launch all kernels minus one, so that you can work on the last one?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, of course I could (I mentioned that in the question). But I think of that as a last resort, because I would loose that core for calculation. Normal office workflow is not very CPU intensive. I want Word or a browser to open quickly and then I stare for a for some seconds at the screen while the CPU does nothing useful...

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Anyway, would 3 processes running at full speed not be better than 4 at idle speed?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I don't think so (also depends on what else is running on the system). I'll do some benchmarks...

Comment: There's this [semi-freeware program Prio](http://www.prnwatch.com/prio.html) that seems to permanently set process priority. Never used it, so can't tell if it's any good.

Comment: I use Mathematica's parallel computation capabilities every day.  In my experience it does what it does very well as long as one keeps everything pretty basic and don't disturb or try to abort parallel computations.  I've also run into problems like locking up of remote machines and Mathematica crashing when I've attempted to configure it beyond default settings.  To be fair, that may reflect more on my code than on the the support for parallel processing, but it does seem to do best when I keep things a simple as possible.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I've used [this](http://retired.beyondlogic.org/solutions/processutil/processutil.htm) command line utility to change process priorities. But this would change all the MathKernels, which is not what I would like.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here are two possible approaches.

#### Using initialization code

Firstly, one notes that the process priority is set (in `AddOns/Applications/SubKernels/LocalKernels.m`) using

```
SetSystemOptions["ProcessPriority" -> -1];
```

where the numeric value corresponds to a priority as follows:

- `-2`: low
- `-1`: below normal
- `0`: normal
- `1`: above normal
- `2`: high

Process priorities on Windows are rather complex and it doesn't seem like there's a way to set idle priority directly, but low will probably be good enough. To execute this code in each subkernel after launch, you just need to evaluate:

```
Needs["Parallel`Developer`"]; (* Load required package *)
$InitCode = Hold[System`SetSystemOptions["ProcessPriority" -> -2];];
```

and now each kernel's process priority will change from normal to low shortly after it starts.

#### Starting local kernels as if they were remote

Another, Windows-specific, approach is as follows. I will use this essentially as an excuse to post the command needed to start remote kernels on Windows where we usually do not have `ssh` available; I found the widely cited [Remote Kernel Strategies](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7250/) presentation less than helpful here and devised this alternative, which I believe works better than other approaches.

We use the [`rcmd`/`rcmdsvc`](http://www.dynawell.com/download/reskit/microsoft/win2000/rcmd.zip) executables from the Windows 2000 Resource Kit, which must be installed first (although the installation is utterly trivial). *Mathematica*'s installation directory must also be in the system's `PATH` environment variable for the `math` command to execute properly on the remote computer (even if in reality this is the same as the local computer).

We now change `` SubKernels`RemoteKernels`$RemoteCommand `` as follows:

```
SubKernels`RemoteKernels`$RemoteCommand :=
 "runas /savedcreds /user:\"`3`\" /noprofile \"rcmd \\\\`1` start /b " <>
  If[SubKernels`LocalKernels`Private`lowerprio, "/LOW", "/NORMAL"] <>
   " math -noinit -subkernel -mathlink -linkmode Connect `4` -linkname `2`\"";
```

The username (slot 3) defaults to the username of the logged-on user but can be changed using e.g.

```
SubKernels`RemoteKernels`$RemoteUserName = "mathematica";
```

Each remote kernel configured with this option will start with reduced priority, depending on whether or not the option is set for local kernels. While it isn't ideal for the process priority for remote kernels to be set using the tickbox on the Local Kernels tab, this option has to be set somewhere and short of adding our own checkbox this seemed like the most reasonable choice. Remote hosts can also be used, of course, if you have them available; if you want to save this command line for each of the hosts set up (say, you want to set up both Windows and Linux hosts, and need to use a different command line for each) then tick the "Use custom launch command" box when configuring the host.

Comment: Thank you and a big +1! An unrelated question: Any reason why you prefer `rcmd` over the multitude of [ssh servers for windows](http://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows)?

Comment: @Ajasja because it's easy to install and more tightly integrated with the Windows way of doing things (for example, communication is done using a named pipe) so you don't have to set up user accounts or do any other configuration beyond what already exists in Windows. If you're on a domain, everything's in place already. I frequently use OpenSSH under Cygwin to access Linux hosts, but it's complicated to set up and not really necessary for Windows-to-Windows communication, especially on a local network. (I assume nobody would run remote kernels on computers only accessible via the Internet.)

Comment: Just to mention: I have to add ``Unprotect[Parallel`Developer`$InitCode]`` for this to work.

Comment: @Ajasja Alright... sorry, I forgot to mention that you have to load the ``Parallel`Developer`` package first. I think you've probably not launched any kernels or loaded the package before doing this, so please see the edit. :)

Comment: Mathematica's installation directory must also be in the system's PATH **even if you specify the whole file name to the kernel**!

Comment: @Ajasja oh! Well, that certainly explains the strange behavior you observed!

Comment: Yes, I guess it should be working with rcmd as well. But now that I have sshd on all the boxes I'm not going back:)

Comment: Out of curiosity: is it possible to set the CPU affinity of the kernels? `SystemOptions["*Affinity*"]`  was not encouraging:) And probably the performance gain would be small...

Comment: @Ajasja yes, `start` takes an `/AFFINITY` switch. But as far as I know you can't do this from within *Mathematica*.

Comment: Yup, thanks, then the second approach is the only way to go.

Answer (score 5):

This works on Windows to start the subkernels with low priority, though I think Oleksandr's approach is better.

```
Needs["SubKernels`LocalKernels`"]
Block[{$mathkernel=$mathkernel<>" -threadpriority=-2"},LaunchKernels[]]
```