# Package found with `Needs`, but not with `ParallelNeeds`

Tags: parallelization, configuration

I want to use a self-written package in a parallel computation. However while `` Needs["mypackage`"] `` works without problems, `` ParallelNeeds["mypackage`"] `` can't open my package.

The immediate reason is related to the fact that I added to `$Path`, and the package is in one of the directories I've added. `ParallelTable[$Path,{1}]` reveals that this addition is not propagated to the subkernels, despite the fact that it is changed in the user kernel init file (`$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m`), and thus long before any subkernels are launched in the Notebook. Explicitly using `DistributeDefinitions[$Path]` didn't help either.

So my question is: Why isn't the $Path propagated to the kernels, and more importantly, what can I do about it?

Comment: It seems symbols in the `System`` context aren't distributed at all

Comment: If case you used my AddPath solution, I updated the answer with an easier way to deal with parallel kernels and argument completion.

Answer (score 8):

You can just add you package path to the path on each of the kernels

```
ParallelEvaluate[AppendTo[$Path, ToFileName[{$HomeDirectory, "MyPackages"}]]]
```

now running

```
ParallelTable[$Path, {1}]
```

will show that the change has been propagated.

---

Besides using an `init.m` file, there is another way to run code on each kernel after start-up (full credit goes to this [excellent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7117/745) by Oleksandr R.)

```
Needs["Parallel`Developer`"]; (* Load required package *)
$InitCode = Hold[AppendTo[$Path, ToFileName[{$HomeDirectory, "MyPackages"}]]];
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my immediate problem (actually it's simple enough that I should have gotten that idea myself). However, I still wonder why this is necessary at all, and how to solve it in general (I'd prefer not to have to do that every time I do a parallel evaluation; OTOH I don't want to unnecessarily start parallel kernels from my `init.m`).

Comment: @celtschk Perhaps the subkernels have their own `init.m` file somewhere. or can be configured to read another file using `-initfile xxx`. But quickly browsing the docs, I have not found anything useful yet.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. This brought me on the right track. I don't know if this is documented somewhere, but I've now found out that after ``Needs["SubKernels`"]`` there is a variable ``SubKernels`Protected`stdargs`` with value `" -subkernel -noinit"`. Setting it to just `" -subkernel"` (before launching the subkernels) causes the subkernels to load the init file.

Comment: @celtschk that could be in a self-answer, I'd upvote it

Comment: @Rojo: Thanks, done.

Comment: @celtschk glad to be of help:)

Answer (score 8):

I've now found the solution.

The reason that the path is not available is that it is set in an init file, and subkernels do not execute any init files. However, as it turns out, the reason why they do not execute any init files is that they are explicitly passed the option `-noinit` when started (you can easily see that by looking at the process listing on your OS; e.g. on Linux, `ps x` reveals the command line if the window is wide enough).

How to change the options on start does not seem to be documented, however I've found out that in the package `` SubKernels` `` there exists a variable `` SubKernels`Protected`stdargs `` which contains a string with the (non-mathlink) arguments passed to subkernels. By default it has the value `" -subkernel -noinit"`. Therefore executing the following before launching the subkernels causes them to execute the standard initialization file:

```
Needs[SubKernels`]
SubKernels`Protected`stdargs = " -subkernel"
```

Obviously this can also be used to pass other options to the subkernels (an obvious candidate would be `-initfile` to have separate initialization for main and sub kernels, however I haven't tested that yet).

Comment: I think the reasoning behind all that might be that the parallel kernels don't necessarily run on the same machine and don't necessarily see the same file system -- thus every kernel could in such a szenario read a different init file -- not a very reliable environment. For just getting your parallel job up and running I think what you do is perfectly good, but if you give away code or want to run on a cluster letting the kernels read an init file might not always be a good idea. The same is of course true for package files - in general you'd have to ensure there are available to every kernel

Comment: @AlbertRetey: Actually where I'm working, all computers mount the very same file system at the very same position (with the exception of local scratch space which, being local, is of course different on all computers). And that is how it should be. Anyway, the whole `ParallelNeeds` concept already presumes that the same package is available on all computers. Also, if there are different file systems on the different computers, then there would also be different init files which then would also set up the different paths correctly for those different environments.

Comment: sorry, my above comment was mixing two different things: What I actually had in mind is what the reasoning to not distribute `$Path` from the master to the slave kernels by default might be. I think that was your original question and from your comment I think we agree that automatically distributing `$Path` would in general have the potential to break such a setup...

Comment: ... The `-noinit` options is a slightly different story, but I can well understand why WRI decided to have it set for the slave kernels: I hardly have seen personal init files that would have worked for a heterogenous environment, so that I'd expect a lot of error messages on kernel startup for many users launching kernels in such an environment with initialization switched on. Other reasons might be performance considerations and to ensure a uniform minimal setup among all slave kernels.

Comment: If you use Autoload packages, they will load *even with `-noinit`*. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114957/12

Answer (score 7):

I use the following solution for this problem:

- I have a package called `AddPath` which can add pre-defined directories to the `$Path`.  This package is placed in `$UserBaseDirectory/Autoload`, so [it gets loaded on parallel kernels as well](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114955/12).
- I put another very basic package in `Autoload` which simply contains

  ```
  Needs["AddPath`"]
  AddPath[{"Pack1","Pack2",...}]
  ```

  Then I always have these packages available in the `$Path` both on the main kernel and subkernels.

Caveat: In order for a package to load from Autoload, [it must follow a certain structure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114957/how-to-use-the-autoload-directory).

I also use a `ParallelAddPath` function which registers packages to be added to the `$Path` on newly started parallel kernels. In this way it is similar to `ParallelNeeds`. Implementation details:

- [Register "initialization code" to run on any newly started parallel kernel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131856/12)

Finally, I set up argument-completion for `AddPath` to make it easier to type. Implementation notes:

- [Argument completions for user-defined functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56984/12)

I realize that this is overkill, and you could just create a file `Autoload/MyInit/init.m` which contains `AppendTo[$Path, ...]`.  But I have been using this AddPath setup for quite a while and it works well for me, so I thought I would share it. I also think it is relevant for a question about changing `$Path`. Note: I only started using the Autoload part today though, before that I used the standard `init.m` to load AddPath.

---

I originally came up with `AddPath` for version management (I had multiple versions of packages I was developing) and dependency management.  I looks roughly like below.

```
BeginPackage["AddPath`"]

AddPath::usage = "AddPath[\"package\"] will add \"package\" to the $Path."
RemovePath::usage = "RemovePath[\"package\"] will remove \"package\" to the $Path."
ParallelAddPath::usage = "ParallelAddPath[\"package\"] will register \"package\" to be added to the $Path on parallel kernels.";

Begin["`Private`"]

Get["AddPath`Config`"];

AppendTo[packageList, _ -> Null];
AppendTo[dependencies, _ -> {}];

AddPath::path = "The package `` is already in the $Path.";
AddPath::pack = "`` is not a known package.";

SetAttributes[AddPath, Listable]
AddPath[pack_String] := 
    Module[{deps, path},
        Quiet@AddPath@Replace[pack, dependencies];
        path = Replace[pack, packageList];
        If[path === Null,
            Message[AddPath::pack, pack];
            Return[]
        ];
        If[MemberQ[$Path, path],
   Message[AddPath::path, pack];
   Return[]
  ];
  AppendTo[$Path, path];
    ]

RemovePath::path = "The package `` is not in the $Path.";
RemovePath::pack = AddPath::pack;

(* RemovePath will not check for equivalent path names.
   ~/dir and /Users/someone/dir are considered different *)

SetAttributes[RemovePath, Listable]
RemovePath[pack_String] :=
    Module[{path},
        path = Replace[pack, packageList];
        If[path === Null,
            Message[RemovePath::pack, pack];
            Return[]
        ];
        If[Not@MemberQ[$Path, path],
   Message[RemovePath::path, pack];
   Return[]
  ];
  $Path = DeleteCases[$Path, path];
    ]


ParallelAddPath[arg : (_String|{___String})] :=
    (Parallelize;
     ParallelNeeds["AddPath`"];
     Parallel`Protected`AddInitCode[
         Parallel`Client`HoldCompound[AddPath[arg]]
     ];)


(* Set up argument completion. *)
addCompletion = FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`AddSpecialArgCompletion[#]] &;    
addCompletion[# -> {Most[packageList][[All, 1]]}]& /@ {"AddPath", "RemovePath", "ParallelAddPath"};

End[] (* `Private` *)

EndPackage[]
```

I manually edit `packageList` and `dependencies` in `Config.m` whenever I need to.  These define the package locations (usually Git repos) and their dependencies.

```
packageList = {
  "Spelunking" -> "~/Repos/Spelunking",
  "SciDraw" -> "~/Documents/Mathematica/SciDraw-0.0.7/packages",
   ...
  "MATLink10" -> "~/Documents/Mathematica/MATLink10",  (* example of multiple versions of the same package *)
  "MATLink11" -> "~/Documents/Mathematica/MATLink11",
  "MATLink1Dev" -> "~/Repos/MATLink1",
   ...
  "LTemplate" -> "~/Repos/LTemplate",
  "IGraphM" -> "~/Repos/IGraphM",
  ...
  _ -> Null
};

dependencies = {
  ...
  "IGraphM" -> "LTemplate",
  ...
  _ -> {}
};
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to elevate `packagList` and `dependencies` to package level variables, and then set them in `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]` with `_ -> Null` appended internally. Additionally, I think I would merge the two and use `"package" -> {path, dependency ..}` or `"package" -> {path, "Dependencies" -> {dependency ..}}`, instead. But, that's just me.

Comment: @rcollyer You're right, that makes complete sense (except for the part of setting them in `init.m`, which won't be read by parallel kernels).  In fact I *just* moved those out into a separate file.  The reason why this feels half-done is that it *is* half done.  I used it for my own purposes, and it was good enough. I only changed it when something got annoying enough to get me to do something about it. Take it as an idea rather than a ready-to-use implementation.  Overall it did work rather well.

Comment: I hadn't realized `init.m` was only picked up by the master kernel. Overall, I meant them as suggestions. Most of my ideas are half-baked, and only implemented as far as I need them at any given moment (or so over-engineered that changing them when they need updating is "interesting"), so I understand, it is a work in progress.

Comment: @rcollyer I completely agree with your suggestions, and updated the post a bit.  In fact I did something like this on my machine just minutes before I read your comment.

Comment: this is only strictly necessary for versions > 11.2, right? Before that, all my custom packages were perfectly working in parallel evaluations, by simply using ParallelNeeds["package`"] and ParallelEvaluate[AppendTo[$Path, path]];

Comment: @Santi The 11.2 vs 11.3 issue is something else, not related to this answer. The command you describe will not work in any version if you launch additional kernels *after* issuing the ParallelEvaluate / ParallelNeeds