# ToNumberField won't recognize Root as an explicit algebraic number

Tags: equation-solving, bugs, polynomials, version-9, algebraic-manipulation

**Bug fixed in 10.0.0**

---

In *Mathematica 9.0.1*, it appears that `ToNumberField` will not always recognize a `Root` object as an explicit algebraic number.

```
ToNumberField[
    Root[{ 1 - #1 + #1^2 - #1^3 + #1^4 - #1^5 + #1^6 &, 
           #1^5 + #1^3 #2 + #1 #2^2 + #2^3 - #1 #2^3 + #1^2 #2^3 - #1^3 #2^3 + #1^4 #2^3 
          - #1^5 #2^3 - #1^4 #2^4 - #1^2 #2^5 - #2^6 &},  {6, 6}] ]
```

> ```
> ToNumberField::nalg: 
> "Root[{1 -#1 + #1^2 - #1^3 + #1^4 - #1^5 + #1^6&, 
>         #1^5 + #1^3 #2 + #1 #2^2 + #2^3 - #1 #2^3 + #1^2 #2^3 -#1^3 #2^3 + #1^4 #2^3
>        - #1^5 #2^3 - #1^4 #2^4 - #1^2 #2^5 - #2^6 &}, {6,6}]
>   is not an explicit algebraic number. >>"
> ```

A different root of the same polynomial works just fine:

```
ToNumberField[
    Root[{1 - #1 + #1^2 - #1^3 + #1^4 - #1^5 + #1^6 &, 
          #1^5 + #1^3 #2 + #1 #2^2 + #2^3 - #1 #2^3 + #1^2 #2^3 - #1^3 #2^3 + #1^4 #2^3 
          - #1^5 #2^3 - #1^4 #2^4 - #1^2 #2^5 - #2^6 &},  {6, 1}] ]
```

> ```
> AlgebraicNumber[Root[1 + #1 + #1^2 + #1^3 + #1^4 + #1^5 + #1^6 &, 2], {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
> ```

Is this a bug, and is there any way I can work around it?

**Edit**: In case it matters, that first `Root` expression will `FullSimplify` to `1`.

Comment: Possibly related: [http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Mar/msg00531.html](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Mar/msg00531.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in `RootReduce` for `Root` objects representing last coordinates of solutions of triangular systems. The bug affects cases where the last coordinate of the solution is real, but some of the other coordinates are not real. Thanks for pointing it out.

The problem can be fixed with the following patch (you can put it in your `init.m` file).

```
rootReduceFix[r:Root[fs_List, ks_List]] :=
   Module[{X, vars, polys, rts, nr, prec=20},
      vars = X /@ Range[ Length[fs]];
      polys = # @@ vars& /@ fs;
      res = Last[polys];
      Do[ res = Resultant[ res, polys[[i]], vars[[i]]];
          res = Times @@ (First /@ FactorSquareFreeList[res]),
          {i, Length[polys] - 1, 1, -1}];
      rts = Last[vars]/.Solve[ res==0, Last[vars]];
      While[ Length[rts] != 1,
             nr = N[r, prec];
             rts = Select[ rts, # - nr == 0&];
             prec*=2];
      First[rts]]

problemRootQ[r_] := Head[r] === Root && Length[r] == 2 && ListQ[r[[1]]] &&
   (Head[#] === Complex && Im[#] == 0 &[N[r]])

rootReduceFixFlag = True;

Unprotect /@ { RootReduce, ToNumberField};

RootReduce[e_] /; rootReduceFixFlag :=
   Block[{ rootReduceFixFlag=False},
      RootReduce[ e/.(r_?problemRootQ) :> rootReduceFix[r]]]

ToNumberField[args__] /; rootReduceFixFlag :=
   Block[{ rootReduceFixFlag = False},
      ToNumberField @@ ( {args}/.(r_?problemRootQ) :> rootReduceFix[r])]

Protect /@ { RootReduce, ToNumberField};
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't ask for a more helpful answer.

Comment: For anyone else using this patch, getting it to work on parallel kernels requires [this extra step](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11595/package-found-with-needs-but-not-with-parallelneeds).

Comment: Maybe it would be better to surround this with `If[$Version == 9, ...]` to avoid trouble after any future upgrades (since users will likely keep their `init.m` but might forget about modifications).