# Will Version 9 functions all work in Version 10?

Tags: compatibility

Having developed a substantial code base in *Mathematica* 9, leads me to ask these important questions prior to downloading and installing *Mathematica* 10.

Will any *Mathematica* functions from the previous version either not work in *Mathematica* 10 or work differently?

If so, does anyone know of a reference to such changes?

I've looked for one but only find the new features.

Comment: Shouldn't this be in meta?

Comment: Compatibility is usually pretty good, but there's always a small chance that something has changed in a breaking way.  There's no list of such changes.  The best way to test is to run your code.  I recommend that you have M9 and M10 installed side by side (easy and possible) until you are confident that nothing critical got broken in 10.

Comment: The most likely breaking change is the introduction of new function names, which might conflict with functions you defined.  If you never use functions whose names start with capital letters, this won't be a problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs - Thoughtful and noted.  Thanks, I just still remember a version change where all sorts of functions no longer worked.  A simple statement that MMA 10 extends MMA 9 and doesn't upset any of it from Wolfram would do a lot to ease my mind.

Comment: @Öskå - Happy to see this moved to Meta if everyone thinks it makes more sense there.

Comment: Yes, it's an extension of version 9, and it's designed to be compatible.  I recall Wolfram advertising the good backwards compatibility of Mathematica.  But there's always a chance that some things have changed enough to break some code, even if this is a rare situation.  So people won't categorically say that everything that worked in 9 will also work the same way in 10.  In the past many things were broken by the new and vastly improved graphics system of version 6, but there were no major breaking changes since then.

Comment: *"I just still remember a version change where all sorts of functions no longer worked."*  That might have been the introduction of the completely revamped graphics system in version 6.  (You could still load the old behavior with ``<< Version5`Graphics` ``.)  Does that sound right?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Yes that does sound right and oddly comforting to recall some of the details and challenges of those changes.  Thinking about it less specifically just got me a bit worried.

Comment: @Öskå Meta is for questions about *this site* rather than *Mathematica* itself, therefore this question is more appropriate here on the main site.

Comment: @Jagra I keep updating my answer occasionally, perhaps you'll find some new useful tips there.

Comment: @Szabolcs -- I've followed all the comments and answers with GREAT interest.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Multiple versions of Mathematica can co-exist on a computer without problems.  **The best approach is to have both version 10 and version 9 installed simultaneously** until you are confident that all your critical code work with 10.

When using multiple versions it is useful to go to Preferences -> System and check "Create and maintain version specific front end preferences".

It is also good practice to check the kernel [`init.m`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html) after upgrading, if you have ever changed it, especially if you put anything like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23992/12) there and forgot about it.

---

That said, Mathematica generally aims for good backwards compatibility.  Since version 6 there haven't been any major breaking changes.  The most likely source of conflict is the introduction of new names. For example, many people defined `Norm` before version 5 introduced a builtin of the same name.  This is why it is good practice never to use names starting with capital letters: this guarantees that newly introduced names in future versions won't break older code.  (This guideline doesn't apply to packages, which should put everything in a separate [context](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html) to avoid name conflicts.  In fact it's better to use capitalized names in packages for the same reason: avoid conflict with notebook code that doesn't have its own namespace.)

---

The documentation has some information about which functions have changed and how.  The version when the function was last changed is shown at the bottom:

[image]

Changes in the last version can be highlighted:

[image]

This information should not be considered 100% accurate.  There may be accidental omissions.  Some changes may not be noted.  (Though these are less likely to be breaking changes.)

---

**The default plotting styles have changed in Mathematica 10.**  If you have notebooks for generating publication figures, they will not produce the same output any more.

It is not only the colours and thicknesses that have changed, but e.g. `ListPlot` now produces dots with a relative size specification, so they scale with the figure (before it was absolute and the dots didn't scale).  This has affected me personally, but the fix was easy.

It should be possible to revert to the old styles by using the option `PlotTheme -> "Classic"` in plotting functions, or using the global setting

```
$PlotTheme = "Classic"
```

I do not know if this setting reverts all styles fully or not.

**Updates:**

- `PlotTheme -> None` may be a better choice than `"Classic"`, e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54527/12).    This won't reset the font (which will be controlled by the default sans-serif stylesheet).
- For 3D graphics, `"ClassicLights"` needs to be used, e.g. `PlotTheme -> {"Classic", "ClassicLights"}`.  ([Thanks to kguler.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54614/12))

---

As [Bezewy notes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54487/12), some functions, in particular **date handling functions, have different return types**.  `DateDifference` returns a `Quantity` object, i.e. the units (days) are included. This can be converted back using `QuantityMagnitude`.

`DatePlus`, `DateRange`, etc. will return `DateObject` instead of a date list *only if the input is also a `DateObject`*.  So this shouldn't break old code.

`DateObject` can be converted back to the old form (a date list) using [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Normal.html).

```
Normal[Today]
(* {2014, 7, 12, 0, 0, 0.} *)
```

Using `Normal` for this conversion is more convenient than using `DateList` because it will convert every `DateObject` in the expression.  For example, we can do `Normal@DateRange[Today, DatePlus[Today, 10]]`.

Comment: It seems that other (probably better) way to revert to the old styles is `$PlotTheme = None`.

Comment: @Alexey Why do you think it's better?  If there's something that works better with `None`, I'd like to know too.  `None` doesn't revert the fonts to Times, while `"Classic"` does.

Comment: I feel that `None` is just the lesser-surprise option but I have not investigated it in depth. This option looks like disabling the new `$PlotTheme` functionality which makes the trouble.

Comment: @Alexey You're right, [here's why](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54527/12)

Comment: Using `SetSystemOptions["DataOptions" -> "ReturnQuantities" -> False]` you can get back the old behaviour of `DateDifference` (trick from the 'Possible Issues' section).

Answer (score 16):

Some functions have new return types in MM10. For instance, I'm running into trouble with date functions (like DatePlus) since they return DateObjects in MM10 but returned date lists in MM9. Other functions (like DateDifference) now return Quantity objects instead of a number.

Comment: can you please post small example?

Comment: `DateDifference[{2014, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 2}] == 1` returns `True` in MM9 but `1 day == 1` in MM10.  As for DatePlus, looks like it's not a compatibility problem after all since it only returns a DateObject if given a DateObject.

Comment: If the Wolframians keep up the standards they honored until now, then I expect my version 4.0 code to still live and kick as it does in in version 9.0. Minor modifications like dropping 'GraphicsArray' are to be taken in the stride. So, I'm positive about downward compatibility.

Comment: It seems the added `Quantity` to the result. So now one needs to do `DateDifference[{2014, 1, 1}, {2014, 1, 2}] == Quantity[1, "Day"]` which returns `True`

Comment: Right. I ended up adding `QuantityMagnitude` to the other side instead.  Concerning the original question posted, I see that the v10 documentation marks functions like DateDifference as "Modified". Assuming that the docs are in some structured format somewhere inside Wolfram, I'm guessing it would be fairly simple for them to produce a list of modified functions, no?

Comment: Simple and considerate IMHO.

Comment: Haven't got 10 yet but generally at the bottom of a docs page they give the version that the function was created and the version it was last updated.

Comment: Using `SetSystemOptions["DataOptions" -> "ReturnQuantities" -> False]` you can get back the old behaviour of `DateDifference` (trick from the 'Possible Issues' section).

Answer (score 9):

One difference I just run into is Dispatch. To get the original rules, use First@Dispatch[•••] in v9, but Normal@Dispatch[•••] in v10.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to let everyone know what happened to me in case it prevents the stress I'm feeling right now. I was worried about the changes in the way dates are handled as I have many lines of code with date features as I am backtesting investments. I decided to see what happens and if I could fix any issues with great inputs above.

I made sure not to uninstall version 9 so I figured it was a safe test. Well, I could not figure out how to easily fix all my date commands with "Normal@" unfortunately. It did work for some of them. So anyway I was very disappointed that installing 10 corrupted my version 9 date commands breaking my script even on version 9! No, a reboot did not reset this, and I did not save any changes on my working script.

So now my script is broken and I have to produce data in a couple weeks, and this is not my day job. I guess I will try uninstalling everything and reinstalling only 9 so I can sleep at night. Be careful out there trying out 10 if you have deadlines to meet. I don't like to post negative comments but I also don't want someone else to go through what I did. Installing 10 should not mess with 9 but it did in my case. They need to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Each new release of *Mathematica*, from V6 on at least, has come with a compatibility checker that intervenes each time you open a notebook created in an earlier version and warns you of code that it thinks might break because of revisions to functions that were part of previous releases. I don't have V10 yet, but I would expect it to a compatibility checker, too. Perhaps someone who has already obtain V10 can confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience of opening a version 9 notebook in version 10 had no such warnings at all, that I could see. Also I looked for compatibility checker and found none. It could exist but I didn't find it.

When I had an issue with version 9 being corrupted by V10 install, system restore did not fix the issue to my wide eyed amazement. Also, uninstalling both versions and reinstalling only 9 did not work! The same notebook opened on another computer with version 9 ran fine. Difference is that system never had 10 installed. Very strange.