# Geodesy without units?

Tags: string-manipulation, units, geodesy

Suppose I'm interested in the latitude of Los Angeles and I do the following:

```
In[1]:= c1 = CityData[{"LosAngeles", "California", "UnitedStates"}];
In[2]:= Latitude[c1]
Out[2]= Quantity[34.0194, "AngularDegrees"]
```

So the latitude is a Quantity! And if I get the string value I get:

```
In[4]:= ToString[Latitude[c1]]
Out[4]= "34.0194 degrees"
```

This seems a little at odds with the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Latitude.html) where the examples seem to show a plain number being output.

Quantities are all well and good until I want to, say, use the Google Directions Api:

```
In[6]:= address = 
 ToString@StringForm[
   "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=`1`,`2`", Latitude[c1], Longitude[c1]]
Out[6]= "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=34.0194 degrees,-118.411 degrees"
```

That's not at all what I want!

I suppose I can get the magnitude of the Quantity to get something more like what I want:

```
In[7]:= address = 
 ToString@StringForm[
   "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=`1`,`2`", QuantityMagnitude[Latitude[c1]], QuantityMagnitude[Longitude[c1]]]

Out[7]= "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=34.0194,-118.411"
```

But that's beginning to feel like I'm straining and probably not doing it right. Is there a better way of dealing with these units?

Comment: have you tried `Latitude[c1][[1]]` and `Longitude[c1][[1]]`?

Comment: The discrepancy between your result and the documentation is probably because those functions didn't return units in previous versions of *Mathematica*. Re. your question: Try using `QuantityMagnitude`, for example `QuantityMagnitude@Latitude[c1]`.

Comment: That produces the right result, of course.  Maybe that's the expert's idiom.  I'm such a beginner at Mathematica that I'm using more explicit forms so that _I_ know what the code is saying. I was also hoping it was "better code". Even in this form, however, I'm still picking the magnitude out of the Quantity.

Comment: @Pickett, the change to having Latitude return a Quantity seems like it would have broken existing code that was producing strings from values. That's kinda why I'm wondering if there isn't a backwards-compatibility feature or something.

Comment: Using `SetSystemOptions["DataOptions" -> "ReturnQuantities" -> False]` you can get back the old behaviour (trick from the 'Possible Issues' section of `DateDifference`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will Version 9 functions all work in Version 10?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54481/will-version-9-functions-all-work-in-version-10)

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of that question in any meaningful sense.  Yes, this is a function that works differently in 10 than 9, but it doesn't really answer my "is there a better way" question.  Incidentally, setting "ReturnQuantities"->False doesn't seem to change anything. `In[12]:= SystemOptions["DataOptions"]

Out[12]= {"DataOptions" -> {"ReturnEntities" -> True, 
   "ReturnQuantities" -> False, "UseDataWrappers" -> True}}
In[13]:= Latitude[c1]

Out[13]= Quantity[34.0194, "AngularDegrees"]`.  Maybe there isn't a better way?