# How do I tweak the input assistant to use string completion on my own functions?

Tags: front-end, function-construction

I would like to be able to use Mathematica's string completion feature for subvalues of my own functions. I tend to go for functions that follow the pattern `f["description"][parameters][variables]` So say I have functions describing models:

```
modelOfSomething["Linear"][a_, b_][x_]:= a + b x;
modelOfSomething["Logarithmic"][a_, b_][x_]:= a + b Log[x];
```

Then as time goes on, I define more functions:

```
modelOfSomething["NonLinear"][a_, b_, c_, n_][x_] := 
  modelOfSomething["Linear"][a, b][x] + c x^n;
```

so as I go along, I may end up with a few different models that I find useful to index with a string especially if they have the same number of parameters. So my  question is

> if/how can I get Mathematica to give me a drop-down of all the string subvalues of my function much like it does with `CountryData`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The method described in [File-name completion for custom functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57062/142) can be used to complete the *"description"* argument in your examples, but it won't work for the curried *parameters* and *variables*.

Note that the method does not appear to support dynamic computation of completion choices, so it cannot be used to generate the list directly from a symbol's definitions.  The list would have to be maintained independently of the definitions themselves.

Comment: See, the linked is exactly the question I was looking for before I posted but I thought "string completion" was the right search term - I will see what I can do with it and if it is as easy as your answer there makes it look, I will delete this as duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: Let's close it instead of deleting it -- you won't be the last person to use that search term.