# Prompt a set of possible options

Tags: front-end, options, customization, autocomplete

Recent versions of Mathematica dynamically prompt a list of possible options. For example, when typing

```
Plot[x, {x,0,1}, PlotStyle->
```

After typing the arrow, Mathematica prompt a list `Gray, Dashed, Thick` for choice. How to define similar behavior for user defined functions? For example,

```
Options[myFun] = {myOpt -> value};
myFun[OptionsPattern[]] := 1;
```

How to prompt a set of possible options, like `opt1, opt2, opt3` right after typing

```
myFun[myOpt->
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Thanks for asking this question; I might not have discovered this customizable area without it.

The auto-completion option values are automatically loaded on Front End start from:

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd",
  "SystemResources", "FunctionalFrequency", "OptionValues"}]
```

This directory contains a series of Package (`.m`) files each with the name of a function, e.g. `ArrayPlot.m`.  The file name itself determines that this will apply to the function `ArrayPlot`.  It also contains an additional file that appears to apply to all functions: `CommonOptions.m`

The structure of each file is a list of Rules:

```
{Extension -> {"Automatic"}, Trig -> {"True", "False"}}
```

- The right hand side of each rule is always a list of Strings or an empty list `{}`
- Option values that are actual strings must be escaped: `"\"string\""`
- Option names must be Symbols (thanks [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/))

A special Rule form exists for icons within the menu, e.g. from `ArrayPlot.m`:

```
PlotTheme ->
 {{"\"Web\"", "PlotTheme-ArrayPlot-Web.png"},
  {"\"Minimal\"", "PlotTheme-ArrayPlot-Minimal.png"},
  {"\"Detailed\"", "PlotTheme-ArrayPlot-Detailed.png"},
  {"\"Business\"", "PlotTheme-ArrayPlot-Business.png"},
  {"\"Marketing\"", "PlotTheme-ArrayPlot-Marketing.png"},
  {"\"Scientific\"", "PlotTheme-ArrayPlot-Scientific.png"},
  {"\"Monochrome\"", "PlotTheme-ArrayPlot-Monochrome.png"},
  {"\"Classic\"", "PlotTheme-ArrayPlot-Classic.png"},
  {"\"Default\"", "PlotTheme-ArrayPlot-Default.png"}}
```

Each of these icon files reside in:

```
FileNameJoin @ {$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "SystemResources", "Bitmaps", "Popups", "CodeCompletion", "Thumbnails"}
```

I have not checked to see if other paths are also searched.

As an example I created a new file `foo.m` in the OptionValues directory with the content:

```
{myOption -> {"Doc", "Grumpy", "Happy", "Sleepy", "Bashful", "Sneezy", "Dopey"}}
```

Now after (re)starting *Mathematica*:

[image]

Comment: @Kuba Sorry!  I guess in this case a [stub answer](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/244/121) might have been helpful but I was discouraged from that practice.  I also tried `$UserBaseDirectory` without success.  Thanks for the note regarding option names.

Comment: Don't be, happens :) I'm not after those temporary placeholders either.

Comment: Smashing, I played a bit more with auto-completion feature and I noticed that when you define an enumerated list of options, the way you described above, drop-down list is filtered automatically as you start typing the name of the option, e.g. myOption->Sl.... and drop-down list displays only "Sleepy". 

Two things here, if you want string options then the list becomes {myOption -> { "\"Doc\"", "\"Grumpy"\", etc.... and if you want the drop-down list filtering then when you type myOption-> ..... do not start with the quotes, but simply type letters of your option and press tab or enter.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems changed in version 11. I'm able to successfully replicate your steps in M10.4 but not in M11. Is there any known updates to do that? thanks

Comment: Ok, found the change: the path has been changed to FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components", 
  "AutoCompletionData", "Main", "OptionValues"}]

Comment: I have another question, hoping someone else has already had the same need. Normally it is not recommended to change Mathematica's own folders, so I would add my own folder with options values to PrivatePaths. I have seen the suboption "AutoCompletionDataBase" and modified it adding another folder, but it doesn't work. Is there any why to say to Mathematica to look at a different position for options values?

Comment: @bobknight I am still using version 10.1 so I cannot help with v11 issues.  I don't know if any solution I find for v10.1 will help you but I'll still look.

Comment: Do you know of any ways to integrate this into packages, without modifying Mathematica itself?  [Argument completion is more or less solved :-)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129910/12)  Now I want option completion.  I suspect that ``FE`OVC`` (OptionValueCompletion) may be of use, but I can't get it to do anything but throw front end errors.

Comment: @Szabolcs No I do not.  It may relate to a longstanding (though only recently posted) question of mine: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121059/121 -- should you find and anther to that one (too) please let me know!

Comment: @Szabolcs I've been messing with those ``FE` `` functions and one thing worth noting is that they might well need to be invoked by the code-assist popup menu. Consider this: ``FE`FT[1, "Plot"]``. It spits out the boxes you'd expect to see in that popup after typing ``Plot[`` and pressing the down-guillemet, but forces them through a `NotebookWrite`-like mechanism. That calls ``FrontEnd`TemplateTooltipPacket`` to create those boxes, by the way.

Comment: @bobknight do you still need help with getting it to work without modifying `$InstallationDirectory`? Just use the `"AutoCompletionData"` extension in the [`"PacletInfo.m"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132064/pacletinfo-m-documentation-project)

Comment: @b3m2a1 thank you for that, I'll take a look to it as soon as I will be back to this issue.

Comment: @bobknight alternatively I think you can just stick your directory on `CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {PrivatePaths, "AutoCompletionData"}]`

Comment: Hi @b3m2a1 can you explain step by step how to make this work  for packages without modifying Mathematica installation?