# Some symbols do not auto-complete in version 10 and version 11

Tags: front-end, keyboard, autocomplete, version-11, version-10.2

When I input `Backsub` in *Mathematica* 10.2 and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> after, I couldn't get `Backsubstitution`.
My OS is Windows 8 32-bit.

**Updated**

I found following symbol doesn't auto-complete also.

`CoefficientDomain`

`EliminationOrder`

`MonomialOrder`

`PolynomialForm`

Comment: I can confirm that `Backsubstitution` is not being offered as a hint on my system either (on 10.2 on Win7-64bit). I would suggest that you report that to WRI. As to the Ctrl+K part, that doesn't actually autocomplete a partial match on my system for other keywords either.

Comment: Would someone kindly test my answer below and tell me if it fails?  If it does can you figure out why?  Has the file format or location change?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Location is different, but the file format is the same. It looks like an issue in V11. If one updates `Reduce.m` in ``FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components", "AutoCompletionData", "Main", "OptionValues"}]`` one doesn't get offered `Backsubstitution` after one writes `Bac`, but if one fully spells out `Backsubstitution` one finally gets `True` / `False` selection box.

Answer (score 4):

1. Please refer to: [Prompt a set of possible options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78935/121)
2. Make a backup, then open `Reduce.m`
3. Edit it to read:

   ```
   {Cubics -> {"True", "False"}, GeneratedParameters -> {}, 
    Quartics -> {"True", "False"}, Backsubstitution -> {"True", "False"}}
   ```
4. Save the file
5. Restart *Mathematica*
6. Enjoy the result

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't worked as exepted on my PC.

Comment: I am running version 10.1.0 so I cannot rule out a change in 10.2.0 but it surprises me.  I take it the appropriate file did exist on your system, and its contents were as above *except* for the missing `, Backsubstitution -> {"True", "False"}` part?