# How to use alphabetical autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete

Mathematica maintains a file with the history of commands input by the user (under `$UserBaseDirectory/.Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/SystemResources/FunctionalFrequency/`), so as to provide better suggestions in autocomplete. However I personally prefer a more consitent experience, where I always get suggestions in alphabetical order. Is there a way to configure autocomplete so that suggestions are always listed in alphabetical order, instead of using cues from my history?

Comment: See also: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/806341

Answer (score 2):

Not currently.  You should understand though that data from your autocompletion history is just one factor that determines the order of completions.  There are other terms in the weighting equation which come from other sources of usage data in a given context.  Strictly alphabetical ordering can be problematic too, and you may wind up typing more characters to narrow things down.

Comment: Would you be willing to complete the missing information [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129910/12)?  What I want specifically is to be able to autocomplete something else than a simple string in an argument.  Example: one of the completions offered in `GraphData` is `{"Knight", {2, 3}}`, which is a list, not a string.  Is this possible without using `.trie` files?  If not, do we users have access to tools to create such `.trie` files?

Comment: Another question: can we set up auto-completion for option values for user-defined functions?  [Here's the question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78935/12), but the existing answer is about modifying the Mathematica installation.  I am not interested in doing that.  All I want is some option value suggestions for certain options/functions I defined in my own package.  It's to make the package more user-friendly.