# How to create a function with option that shows dropdownlist like ( for example ) Manipulate with ControlPlacement?

Tags: function-construction, customization, optional-arguments

Consider the *Mathematica* function `Manipulate` where you assign the placement of the controls with the option parameter `ControlPlacement`, i.e.

```
ControlPlacement -> Top
```

Now assume I want to create a function `f`:

```
f[x_, option_] := ( ... )
```

That is, I assume this is the way to define the functionality I require.

I want the option parameter to have values from

```
opts := {1 -> "A", 2 -> "B", 3-> "C", 4-> "D", 5-> "E"}
```

such that when I enter the function that when I type option, a dropdownlist appears showing `A, B, C, D` and `E`.

How do I create this functionality for a function?

I don't think it is, as suggested in the comments, custom completion ( which is still being developed for version 12.+ ).

Comment: I think this is covered quite well in the documentation https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments.html

Comment: Is this what you need? [Prompt a set of possible options](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78935/5478)

Comment: Sounds like you want [this feature](https://youtu.be/fz8yznsivPc?t=13m35s), which is not yet part of the release version. Or did it get another name?

Comment: How can it not be in the release yet if  'Manipulate' itself has it?

Comment: @Kuba thanks will look at that

Comment: I don't quite understand why do you want. "...when I type option, a dropdownlist appears showing A, B, C, D and E." - what do you mean by type option, and assuming e.g. `1`, why would other characters appear on a dropdown?

Comment: @Kuba can you please provide the code you used? I am just confused about this particular functionality of Mma. Thanks.

Comment: What code? I haven't done anything. I'm just asking how the feature you are talkin about differes from the linked one and I ask about calrification of doubts I have.

Comment: You said "when I type option, a dropdownlist appears showing A, B, C, D and E." so how did you do that? That's all I am asking.

Comment: @niloderoock you said that, that is why I've used quotes...

Comment: You leave me completely in the dark, @Kuba

Comment: "...when I type option, a dropdownlist appears showing A, B, C, D and E." - thse are your words, have you read your post? :)