# Why auto-completion menu selection gives error?

Tags: autocomplete

Is this supposed to happen? I used the auto-completion menu and selected a valid value it shows (first one from the menu), then Mathematica complained that the choice selected is not valid !

```
ClearAll[x];
Solve[Tan[x] == 1, x, MaxExtraConditions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Should not all choices shown be valid for the command they show up for?

Comment: I'd bet that's a simple bug. Someone at WRI gave that as an [option completion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/82697/38205) and clearly it isn't. Either that or they changed the `Solve` internals and it is no longer. Either way, seems buggy to me.