# How to have Mathematica showing a dropdown list after entering an option and the -> in a function argument

Tags: options, optional-arguments

When I enter

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Mathematica returns, as expected, the expected Sinus wave of one period.

Plot has many, many options, when I enter:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes ->]
```

the Mathematica Notebook Interface immediately shows a dropdown list with options like

```
False
True
{True, False}
etc.
```

This is obviously expected behaviour, and the behaviour I want to copy in my own functions.

I have been looking into the documentation about

```
Options
OptionsPattern
OptionValue
```

I have read through answers here, and in Wolfram Community, but I am not sure if I am on the right track.

How do I create the behaviour of Mathematica showing a dropdown list after entering an option and the -> ( rule arrow ).

NOTE

Suggestions to other questions answering my questions in the comments do not answer my question. The answers are written for people already familiar with Options, etc.

Comment: Also see [`ResourceFunction["AddCodeCompletion"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AddCodeCompletion) (which is linked from the above question)

Comment: Upon further consideration, [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78935/prompt-a-set-of-possible-options/82697#82697) might actually be a closer fit to yours.

Comment: Thank you, @LukasLang I will study these questions.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Looks good, I am still studying.

Comment: Actually, I am looking for a working example that I can use to build my code on.