# Argument completions for string sequence

Tags: front-end

I want to add completion for string sequence like

```
addCompletion[expr___] :=
    FE`Evaluate@FEPrivate`AddSpecialArgCompletion[expr];

list=Alphabet[];
f[x__String]:=(
    addCompletion["f"->{list}];
    {x}(*some codes here*)
);
```

Here `addCompletion` is from [Argument completions for user-defined functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56984/argument-completions-for-user-defined-functions), and `list` stores some long strings that can be modified by some other functions.

But now only the first argument of `f` can be completed. I tried (and am not satisfied)

```
$fcompletion=4;

f[x__String]:=(
    addCompletion["f"->Table[list,$fcompletion]];
    {x}(*some codes here*)
);
```

Is there a method of completion adapted for `__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple answer. We can wrap the string sequence by `List` or `Association`, then the strings are all in the first argument.

```
setArgumentCompletion[{"f"}][{"a","b"},{"c","d"}];
f[x_]:={x};
```

where `setArgumentCompletion` is basically `` FEPrivate`AddSpecialArgCompletion `` from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/195670/86893.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You know how to set that completions in a case like this: `functionname->{option->{suboption1, subption2}}`. I've tried, but the sub-options don't show up.

Comment: @E.Chan-López you may try this one https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78935/86893. Currently I stop using ``FEPrivate`AddSpecialArgCompletion `` since this is quite unstable and can cause the frontend broken.

Comment: Thanks, Lacia, you're really kind for giving me this information :-)