# Create auto-completion for Wolfram Entity framework related functions when using with user-defined entity store

Tags: entity, language-design

I am trying to create autocompletion for my custom entity store, for example in the document of `EntityStore`

```mathematica
store = EntityStore["fruit" -> <|
    "Entities" -> <|
      "banana" -> <|"color" -> Yellow|>,
      "lime" -> <|"color" -> Green|>,
      "orange" -> <|"color" -> Orange|>,
      "raspberry" -> <|"color" -> Red|>,
      "strawberry" -> <|"color" -> Red|>
      |>
    |>]
```

After registering this store `EntityRegister[store]`. When typing `Entity["`, it did include `fruit` in the completion that appeared, and the next arguments do not include related properties too.

I have looked at this [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56984/argument-completions-for-user-defined-functions) and this [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78935/prompt-a-set-of-possible-options) but seemly they are not related. I cannot find `Entity` in `specialArgFunctions.tr`. Even when I try to find it in `$InstallationDirectory`, I cannot trace back how the autocompletion of `Entity` framework works

I can create my own `FruitData` function, similar to `CityData` or similar functions, and add my own completion using known methods, but that is another story. In this post I am trying to understand how `Entity` function or related functions do their own completion, did they dynamically create autocompletion choices or we must define those completions in some ways