# Creating compiled search TRIE file for argument string completion

Tags: front-end, files-and-directories, customization, autocomplete

I'd like to generate a compiled search TRIE file (like those found in `$InstallationDirectory\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\SystemResources\FunctionalFrequency\`) to help implement the auto-completion feature on user-defined functions.

As described in [File-name completion for custom functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56984), I could directly add a list of strings into the specialArgFunctions.tr file. However, my lists of arguments is long and likely to change during development, so I'd prefer to point to a TRIE file that I can update as needed.

How can I create a compiled TRIE file?  Can this be done in Mathematica or Workbench?  Is the TRIE file extension structure documented anywhere?

---

> b3m2a1 comment:
>
> These files are here in v11:
>
> ```
> FileNames["*.trie", 
>   PacletFind["AutoCompletionData"][[1]]["Location"],
>   Infinity
>  ]
> ```
>
> Similarly in 11 is [`` CA`CADumpTriePacket ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13452/38205) which seems to extract the properties from a trie file, but not the trie format itself.

Comment: Duplicate of [441](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/441/can-a-trie-be-implemented-efficiently)?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, Thanks for the link to [441](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/441/can-a-trie-be-implemented-efficiently), but I am not asking about general practices for implementing a trie data structure in Mathematica. I am looking for the specific TRIE file structure used by Mathematica's FrontEnd.

Comment: You may be interested in this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129910/12  It shows how to add completion without editing `specialArgFunctions.tr`.  What I don't know how to do is enable completion of non-string arguments, as all examples that do this use .trie files and I don't know how to create such files.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks for the suggestion. I will try it out and let you know if I make any progress. Thanks again!