# Special forms for autocompletion strings

Tags: front-end, customization, undocumented

Szabolcs has previously dug up a [very useful tool](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129910/38205) to make custom autocompletions.

Here's that in action:

```
BeginPackage["FI`"]; 
Get["https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/raw/master/Packages/Developer/FunctionInfoExtractor.m"];
EndPackage[];

AddFunctionAutocompletions[
 func,
 {RandomWord[15]}
 ]

{"func" -> {{"coexistence", "fairway", "coonskin", "sensitiveness", 
    "eternally", "lesson", "nitrogenous", "transmutable", 
    "primogeniture", "censorious", "fifthly", "display", "tweet", 
    "ingress", "sanctification"}}}
```

[image]

Playing with his work there and some stuff for [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113116/38205) I hit upon another format for these strings. If we supply the `ToString[..., InputForm]` of a list of strings it'll automatically put the list instead of the raw string:

```
AddFunctionAutocompletions[
 func,
 {
  {ToString[RandomWord[5], InputForm]}
  }
 ]

{"func" -> {{"{\"lead\", \"ascendancy\", \"insolvable\", \"holograph\", \"incongruous\"}"}}}
```

[image]

[image]

Are there any other special forms for this that people know? I understand that this is undocumented, dangerous, will set my machine on fire, precipitate nuclear war, etc. but I'd still like to get the most out of this feature if I can.