# File selection dialog in autocomplete

Tags: files-and-directories, autocomplete

How can I create the autocomplete for the function with opening file selection dialog? For example like a autocomplete of the `SystemOpen`

[image]

UPD: the answer to the question is contained in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56984/argument-completions-for-user-defined-functions)

Comment: See the “custom autocompletions” section. The number you pass to ``FEPrivate`AddSpecialArgFunction`` or whatever it is is like 3 I think. It’s undocumented but on the site somewhere.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Where can I find the "custom autocompletions section"?

Comment: @C.E. Sorry I meant question. Szabolcs has one like this.

Comment: @b3m2a1, You could just leave a link and say that this is a related question, instead of hinting that somewhere there is something similar
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56984/argument-completions-for-user-defined-functions

Comment: @KirillBelov I didn’t have time to track it down when I left that comment