# Creating a Package with autocomplete possibilities

Tags: packages, autocomplete

I'm writing a package (nothing complicated) where I define a lookup function for a defined association.
As an Example:

```
allmycolors =A <|"Blue Special" -> Blue, "Red for fun" -> Red|>
mycolor[c_] := Lookup[allmycolors, c, Yellow]
```

The Key names are describing the color and of course there are many more.
What I would really like is that when using mycolor["...
I get a list of the colors I can choose, use tab and let the system do the autocomplete just like the regular functions.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The method described in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129910/9490) should do what you need.

Comment: @Szabolcs I wonder why I could not find these links.. anyway a lot to read and experiment! Thanks for the pointers.