# Obtain "File Path Completion" with custom functions

Tags: files-and-directories

Suppose I have a function like

```
setDirectory[filePath_ : DirectoryQ] := SetDirectory[filePath]
```

When I start to enter `setDirectory["/home/user.."` I don't get automatic filepath completion like I would if I were using the Wolfram default `SetDirectory["/home/user.."`.  Is there a way to force an argument to a function to receive file path completion aid?

Comment: You should be able to do this using the undocumented functions described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129910/9490)