# Boxes with autocompletion

Tags: front-end, boxes, autocomplete

Entities have this nice autocompletion of properties:
[image]

How do I define autocompletion for my own boxes that behave the same way?

Comment: Auto completion for ordinary user functions is discussed here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56984/ I am not sure how to apply the methods mentioned there (all related to `AddSpecialArgCompletion` from `FEPrivate`) to Subvalue functions/boes.

Comment: @N0va Yeah, I wasn't sure either. That's why I'm asking this question, really want to have autocompletion for my custom objects and not just for some function arguments.

Answer (score -2):

[Here](https://tieba.baidu.com/p/5998955736) is a simple example to implement custom do...end box:

```
ClearAll@do


SetAttributes[do, HoldAll];
do[var_, begin_, end_, body_] := Do[body, {var, begin, end}]


Hold[do /: MakeBoxes[do[var_, begin_, end_, body_], StandardForm] := 
     TemplateBox[MakeBoxes /@ Unevaluated@{var, begin, end, body}, 
      "do", DisplayFunction -> (GridBox[{{RowBox@{RowBox[{style@"do", 
                " ", #}], "=", 
              RowBox[{#2, " ", style@"to", 
                " ", #3}]}}, {RowBox@{"", #4}}, {style@"end"}}, 
          ColumnAlignments -> Left] &)]] /. 
   style[str_] -> StyleBox[str, FontColor -> Darker@Green] // 
  ReleaseHold // ReleaseHold


Hold[CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases, "do"}] = 
    TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]", 
      "\[Placeholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, "do", 
     DisplayFunction -> (GridBox[{{RowBox@{RowBox[{style@"do", 
               " ", #}], "=", 
             RowBox[{#2, " ", style@"to", 
               " ", #3}]}}, {RowBox@{"", #4}}, {style@"end"}}, 
         ColumnAlignments -> Left] &)]] /. 
  style[str_] -> 
   StyleBox[str, FontColor -> Darker@Green] // ReleaseHold
```

When using, first press `Esc` key, then input do, then press `Esc` key to automatically incomplete.

Comment: （-1）This isn't an answer to OP's question at all.

Comment: @xzczd Recently, due to the Great Firewall (block), I can't see the picture in the question. I just guess the answer to this question.