# Autocomplete file argument for custom function

Tags: files-and-directories, autocomplete

When typing `Import["` in a notebook Mathematica suggests to autocomplete the file path you want to enter or choose a file using the GUI. Is there a way to let a custom function also have this behaviour?

For example if I had

```
mySpecialImport[ filepath_String ] := ...
```

then I would like Mathematica to propose files/directories upon entering `mySpecialImport["` just like it does for the built-in Import function.

Comment: related/possible duplicate: [Argument completions for user-defined functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56984/125)