# How to use the autocomplete for built-in function's argument for a user defined symbol?

Tags: units, autocomplete

Suppose I have `myFunction` as follows:

```
ClearAll[myFunction];
myFunction[unitName_,somethingElse_]:=...definition...;
```

I want to use the built-in autocomplete that is used for `Quantity`'s second argument (first for one argument form) for my functions first argument. This autocomplete produces a list of available units to choose from.

I see there are some `Autocomplete` and `AutocompletionFunction` in the documentation but is there a way to achieve this somehow?

Comment: Do you mean you'd like the front end to provide a list of suggestions that could be used for unitName?  Probably, you might want to search for `AddSpecialArgCompletion` on this site.

Comment: There was a similar question years ago, but I forget if anyone found a solution.  Maybe someone remembers it or you can search for it.

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56984/argument-completions-for-user-defined-functions/) is the question I found. But it doesn't contain the instructions to get the auto-complete list for any built-in function. For example, right now I just need the auto-complete list for unit names.