# New Needs alias - How to make autocomplete works

Tags: front-end, autocomplete

Mathematica 13 has a cool new feature for `Needs`. Now it's possible to use alias:

[image]

Here is a simple doc example:
[image]

The problem is, the autocomplete do not work for the Alias! Making life very hard.

Any way to solve that? I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: This _can_ be done via this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56984/argument-completions-for-user-defined-functions#comment437957_129910 but you'll need to curate the list yourself or potentially add ``"ca`"`` to `$ContextPath` but I have to imagine that will break