# How to make Mathematica automatically find packages in subfolders of the Applications directory?

Tags: packages, contexts

Consider our package `awesomepackage.m`.

If I put this file in `FileNameJoin@{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}` I can easily import it in any notebook with a simple `` Needs["awesomepackage`"] `` (or similar command).

The same still works if I put `awesomepackage.m` in a subdirectory of Applications, like in `FileNameJoin@{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications","awesomepackage"}`.

However, if for any reason I want my awesomepackage to be in some subsubdirectory of Applications, then I will have to use its full path, otherwise Mathematica will not be able to find it based on the context name alone.

Is there some convenient way to have Mathematica look for `.m` files *by default* in all (sub..)subdirectories of Applications, maybe up to some nested level?
The core idea is that I want to be able to change the exact location of `awesomepackage.m` without having to change the way it is imported in all the notebooks, and possibly without having to add some code in every notebook in which I want to import this package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The straightforward answer is:  **Do not try to do this!!**  If it were possible, it would break things.

There is a specific (and complicated) way Mathematica resolves file names, which allows the standard application structure to work.  It is described in the Details section of [`FindFile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFile.html).  It does not allow for indefinite recursion into subdirectories.

In order for applications to work the way they do, e.g. it is important that `` foo` `` resolves to `foo/Kernel/init.m` and not to `foo/foo.m` if your directory structure is

```
Applications
    |
    \- foo
        |
        |- foo.m
        |
        \- Kernel
             |
             \- init.m
```

The standard application structure is described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/applications/packages.html).

It is also important that any random `.m` file that may be part of the implementation of a package and is located within a package's directory shouldn't be loadable by its name — unless it is meant to.

Finally, it is not true that Mathematica searches for `.m` files in any subdirectory of `Applications`.  `` foo` `` can resolve to `foo/foo.m` but not to `bar/foo.m`.

---

If you want to organize your packages and applications into multiple directories, you can do so.  But do not put these directories in `Applications` (or into any other location which is already in `$Path`), and add each one separately to `$Path`.

Comment: makes sense. But what if I for example have a big and complex package, composed of multiple `.m` files. I would want the whole thing to be contained in a single directory so to be easily moved and "installed", and at the same time to be able to easily import it in a notebook without having to think of the full paths. What is the recommended method in this case? Should I put a `foo.m` file where you put it in your example, and in `foo.m` write some code to tell MMA where to find the various "subpackages" necessary for the main one?

Comment: by the way, I didn't find a clear explanation of what `init.m` does when inside a package directory structure. Can it be used for such purpuses?

Comment: @glS Say the package is called `Foo`.  Then you have a directory with the same name. Within you have multiple `.m` files, `Sub1.m`, `Sub2.m`, etc.  The `init.m` file contains ``Get["Foo`Sub1`"]; Get["Foo`Sub2`"]; ...``.  You can load the whole package from a notebook using ``<<Foo` ``.  If the sub-packages are somewhat independent and are meant to be loadable separately too, then that can be accomplished using ``<<Foo`Sub1` ``, i.e. the same commands used in `init.m`.

Comment: @glS Very often, there is a sinlge main package file, `Foo/Foo.m` and `init.m` only contains ``Get["Foo`Foo`"]``.  Then as your package is growins and you decide to add more sub-packages that `Foo.m` will depend on, you add them in the same directory as `.m` files and load them in `Foo.m` using ``BeginPackage["Foo`", {"Foo`Sub1`, ...}]``.

Comment: @glS Is your application public by any chance?  If yes, we can discuss it as an example.

Comment: all right, I think I got it. It is also explained in [a section](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/applications/applications.html) of the (very useful) documentation page you provided in the answer. There is no public project yet no, I was considering what the best approach was to make some packages I have more modular and still be able to import and ship them easily between computers. This was very helpful, thanks again!

Comment: @glS I described how I manage my packages [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114963/12).  You may find it useful.  I do not claim that this is the best way, in fact I'm pretty sure it isn't.  But it does help me.  It's something that grew out organically of my own needs, not something deliberately designed to be generally usable.