# Package documentation separately from code

Tags: packages, documentation, paclets

Mathematica documentation is heavy duty stuff. Of the 7.75GB my Mac says Mathematica 11.3 takes up, 5.46 of that is documentation.

So when I write my own packages I don't want to do what WRI did and bloat my system with docs that will most likely never be opened.

How can I distribute my documentation separately from my program? Can I distribute it in such a way that I can easily push updates?

Comment: Does such a package exist whose documentation is so huge that you wouldn't want to install it?

Comment: @QuantumDot documentation can easily balloon in size as packages bloat and the number of symbols increases. I figure it's only kind to any people who choose to use my packages to keep them free of bloat that could be served separately on demand. In a non-object-oriented language if you document each function and each documentation page is at minimum 50 kb it only takes 150 symbols to reach ~10MB of docs. And reaching 150 symbols is easy unless you're careful about your design.

Comment: Oh ok.  Usually, the problem I have with other people's packages is quite the opposite -- *definitely not enough documentation*.

Comment: @QuantumDot that's why I've been working on a system to autogenerate docs :) And that makes documentation bloat even easier...

Answer (score 12):

The trick here is to make a paclet for just your documentation that won't ever interfere with your main package.

To do we'll assume we have a main paclet named `"MyPaclet"`. Then we'll generate its documentation and put it into a new paclet called `"Documentation_MyPaclet"`. This name is chosen to imitate the way the `ServiceConnect` framework names its paclets (as well as many other internal frameworks).

Then to make sure that it loads when we ask for `"MyPaclet"` we'll reassign the `"LinkBase"` argument in the `"Documentation"` extension to be `"MyPaclet"`, as this is how the `` Documentation`ResolveLink `` performs its lookups.

So overall our `"PacletInfo.m"` will look like:

```
Paclet[
 Name -> "Documentation_MyPaclet", 
 Version -> "1.0.0", 
 Extensions -> 
  {
    {
      "Documentation", 
      "Language" -> "English", 
      "LinkBase" -> "MyPaclet", 
      "MainPage" -> "Guides/MyPaclet"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Now when we search for the paclet it will show up, but it won't interfere with `PacletFind` and it won't interfere with loading the paclet. For instance, using some documentation I auto-built:

```
PacletFind["Documentation_BTools*"]
```

[image]

```
PacletFind["BTools"]
```

[image]

What makes this particularly nice, though, is that I can put these paclets on [a paclet server](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132649/38205) and then people can download *just* what they want for documentation--and if I update the documentation it's easy for these updates to mirror.

For instance, if you wanted to install some of my documentation, you could run:

```
PacletInstall["Documentation_BToolsWeb",
 "Site"->"http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.docs/DocumentationServer"
 ]
```

And then you can search for `BToolsWeb` and look at just the part of my documentation that handles web functions in my main package.

If you wanted to update it, you could run:

```
PacletUpdate["Documentation_BToolsWeb",
 "Site"->"http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.docs/DocumentationServer"
 ]
```

And if you wanted to uninstall it so it doesn't bloat your system you can run:

```
PacletUninstall["Documentation_BToolsWeb"]
```

Comment: We do this also, for example with FEMDocumentation.  It is still shipped with Mathematica, but it is structured as a Documentation-only paclet.  So it could in principle be shipped separately, or updated separately, etc...

Comment: @ItaiSeggev I'd really love if more documentation were loaded in an on-demand fashion. Particularly for stuff like the `"Units"` package where the package is already deprecated (of course the heavy hitter is the system-level docs anyway)

Comment: @ItaiSeggev Is it technically feasible to make the FE be able to read gzipped notebooks?  If would result in a very significant saving on the documentation size.

Comment: @Szabolcs that’d be great. Python does something like that for compressing modules.

Comment: @Szabolcs It would have certain costs.  A notebook has structure that allows the FE the only loaded the rough outline, and load other parts on demand as you scroll/open sections.  Gzip would essentially destroy that strucutre, so the FE would need need to either unzip the whole notebook and look at the copy, or read in the whole notebook at opening time.  Either would lead to a significant delay in opening notebooks.

Comment: @ItaiSeggev what about for the little-used functions? Or pages that have very little content to them and hence will load fast no matter what? I imagine that could help a lot with the file bloat. It’s hard to convince my coworkers to install a 7GB behemoth they may only minimally care about...