# Creating Paclet with Workbench

Tags: documentation, workbench, paclets

I've followed [Emerson Willard's guide to creating a paclet with Workbench](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/961186) but am stuck on the step "Build your project and documentation as usual and then create your Paclet file and deploy."  I hit the "Create Paclet" button, enter a destination, then nothing happens.

[image]

Any ideas?  I'm using Mathematica 11.3, MacOS 10.13.4, Workbench 10.1.822.

Should I just try [Szabolcs' approach here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131101/how-to-distribute-mathematica-packages-as-paclets)? (although I might be back for another question or two there!)

Comment: I've never used Workbench but I can attest to the relative simplicity of using Szabolcs' method. If you're really not feeling that (I suggest doing that though) I have a bunch of paclet utilities written into a package of mine that I can write a tutorial or something to.

Comment: Check the procedure for [FEMAddOns](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns) where documentation is build with Workbench and Paclet is made with FrontEnd. I have used this and found it quite convenient.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I gave up on using Workbench to create the paclet and got it working manually, following `FEMAddOns/CreatePaclet.nb` and using `MaTeX` as a model.