# "Auto-loading" a .m file

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories

I have a .m (say e.g. file1.m) file with various definitions that gets sourced by another notebook using the command `` Needs["file1`"] ``. If file1.m is in the ~/.Mathematica/Paclets/Repository, this works, but if it's in the same directory as the notebook, it doesn't.
My question is the following: Can I create a directory in the ~/.Mathematica/Paclets/Repository and put the file1.m file there so that `` Needs["file1`"] `` works (without giving the full path of the file1.m file)? Or I shouldn't because this directory is handled automatically by Mathematica?
Is there another way around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem to be some misunderstandings here.

> I have a .m (say e.g. file1.m) file with various definitions that gets sourced by another notebook using the command `` Needs["file1`"] ``.

[`Needs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Needs.html) is only for loading *packages*, which must follow certain conventions. If you just have a file with definitions, use [`Get`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html), not `Needs`.

For creating packages, see [Creating Mathematica packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29324/12). This requires a lot more than just putting definitions in a file.

> If file1.m is in the ~/.Mathematica/Paclets/Repository, this works ...
>
> Can I create a directory in the ~/.Mathematica/Paclets/Repository and put the file1.m file there ...

Never, ever put anything into `Paclets/Repository`. That directory is managed by functions such as `PacletInstall`, and should not be modified manually.

If you created a package, and want to distribute it to other people, you may want to package it up into a paclet. This involves more than simply creating the package. See [How to distribute Mathematica packages as paclets?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131101/12) for details.

---

If you just want to evaluate the contents of a file, use [`Get`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html). `Get` will look in the current directory ([`Directory`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directory.html)), as well as on the [`$Path`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Path.html). It will not look in the notebook's directory, but you can change the current directory to that using `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]`, or you can pass the full path to the file to `Get`.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your detailed response. I was actually contrasting `CustomTicks` that has only a .m file with `MaTex`, because the latter can be found in /Paclets/Repository whereas the former it's not.