# Hold around SetDelayed with Graphics

Tags: graphics, hold, assignment, initialization

### Minimum Working Example

I've defined my own plot function, which does a lot of stuff to the inputs before passing it into the `Graphics` function. Because of that, I'm using `SetDelayed` and `Module`. Here's a MWE. As expected, this produces no output.

```mathematica
myPlot[x_] :=
 Module[
  {y = x},
  Graphics[y]
  ]
```

### Error

Until now, I've stored this in a notebook which I need to execute every time I open Mathematica. I've recently learned about `$Initialization` and want to use that so I no longer have to manually execute this definition before using it. `$Initialization` requires `Hold`, but as soon as I put Hold around this definition, `Graphics` tries to execute. I get output with a large red square where `Graphics` is in the expression  and the following error.

```mathematica
Hold[
 myPlot[x_] :=
  Module[
   {y = x},
   Graphics[y]
   ]
 ]
```

> y is not a Graphics primitive or directive

I've tried numerous variations of `Hold` and `Defer` (and others) all throughout the expression, both inside and outside `Graphics`, and everything gives the same error.

### Question

**How can I format this function definition with `Hold` around it so that it won't throw an error and will execute when Mathematica runs `ReleaseHold` on it?**

Comment: I don't think this is a problem - it isn't really throwing an error, the `Hold` expression just formats with a pink box in your notebook.  It should work just the same as you expect

Comment: yeah, I think this is just a display thing. The front end is trying to display the Graphics expression. Hold is keeping it from being evaluated, but the front end sees that Graphics expression and wants to display it. At least, that's my guess. I don't see any actual problem going on with the Hold expression itself.

Comment: A better way to define an always available user function is to put the definition  into the "init.m" file

Comment: It doesn't work. I've done `PersistentObjects["*$Initialization"]` and found the *.wl file created by `InitializationValue`. It looks like it stored in the file correctly. Looking at the dozen other expressions which I've put in there and are working, it looks how I'd build it by hand if I tried to edit this *.wl file directly. However, when I go to use my plot function, I get the red box with error message. I think that when `ReleaseHold[$Initialization]` is run, the error occurs again and that expression-with-error is what gets stored as my function.

Comment: @DanielHuber I tried using "init.m" first, but couldn't get it to work for any of the initializations I want. Using `$Initialization`, I've gotten all of them to work but this one.

Comment: I was confused once as well: [114305](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114305/5478), does this topic answer your question?

Comment: Search the web for how to implement autoloading a file with your own definitions. E.g.: `https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219081/auto-loading-a-m-file`

Comment: @Kuba That helps. It points to [32296](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32296/prevent-graphics-from-rendering-inside-a-held-expression) which is a good lead. I now understand what's going on and why, but that solution didn't work. I put the `Unprotect` pattern in my initialization list, both before and after my function definition. Now, when M opens, the pattern stops graphics functions from rendering inside hold functions, but the plot definition is still messed up. I think parallel processing is to blame, where the plot def finishes before the hold pattern def does.

Comment: @DanielHuber I do need to learn that, but I also needed to understand the `Hold`, `Graphics`, `SetDelayed` interaction, hence the question. (Thanks to Kuba for the other links. This is a duplicate question (of [32296](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32296/prevent-graphics-from-rendering-inside-a-held-expression)) even though I searched for those before posting.)

Comment: @Kuba Actually, the `Unprotect` pattern in [32296](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32296/prevent-graphics-from-rendering-inside-a-held-expression) did the trick. I still had an errant `Defer` in my definition from my earlier attempts. I've removed that and now it all works. (I don't know how to mark this question as a duplicate.)