# How does Needs["foo`"] find the file that defines context "foo`"?

Tags: programming, packages, contexts

The post's title says it all, but if more detail is needed:

Suppose I have the following in some file `/path/to/foo.m`:

```
Begin["foo`"];
hello = Function[{}, Print["Hello world!"]];
End[];
```

...and in some other file, say, `./client.m`, I put the following

```
Needs["foo`"];
foo`hello[];
```

Then, when the `Needs` expression gets evaluated, I get the error

```
Needs::nocont: Context foo` was not created when Needs was evaluated.
```

I'm too surprised by this error, since I see no good way for *Mathematica* to find where `` foo` `` is defined.

(BTW, putting `/path/to` in `$Path` does not change the results described above.)

What else must I put in `./client.m`, besides `` Needs["foo`"] ``, so that the expression `` foo`hello[] `` evaluates properly?

---

EDIT: I should explain that the reason I'm using `Begin` instead of `BeginPackage` is that I want to enforce full qualified names (e.g. `` foo`hello ``, rather than plain `hello`) as the only way to refer to imported functions.

Comment: `Needs` calls `Get` which "by default successively searches for files in the directories specified by the elements of $Path."

Comment: @Quantum_Oli: please, see the clarification I added to my post (starting with "(BTW, putting...)").

Comment: @Quantum_Oli: in any case, it stands to reason that putting a path in `$Path` can't possibly be the answer to my question, since there is no relationship between names of files and the names of contexts defined therein.  IOW, a file named `foo.m` need not define a context ``foo` ``, and, conversely, a file named something *other* than `foo.m`, *can* define a context named ``foo` ``.  Since there's no correspondence whatsoever between context names and file names, I see no way in which the content of `$Path` could be used to find the where a context is defined.

Comment: I added some extra notes to the answer to explain the message you get. In short: `Get` just loads a file and doesn't care what is in it. `Needs` should be used to load a package that follows the standard structure.  It uses `Get` internally, but it also does extra checks and avoids double loading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This post answers specifically the title question:

> How does `` Needs["foo`"] `` find the file that defines context `` "foo`" ``?

---

`Get`, `Needs`, `Install`, `OpenRead`, etc. all use [`FindFile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFile.html).  How `FindFile` resolves file names is discussed in:

- [`FindFile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFile.html), Details section
- [Naming and Finding Files](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NamingAndFindingFiles.html)
- [Files for Packages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FilesForPackages.html)

---

I don't know the *full* details (it's complicated), but roughly `FindFile` translates a *context* to a *file path* as follows:

`` FindFile["foo`"] `` either

- Looks on `$Path` for `foo.m`, `foo.wl`, `foo.mx` or directory `foo`
- If a paclet declares the context `` foo` `` in its `Kernel` extension, it translates to the corresponding `Root` directory: See [PacletInfo.m documentation project](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132064/12), Kernel extension section.

Then if the result was a directory `dir`, it continues to look for

- `dir/init.m` (or `init.wl`)
- `dir/Kernel/init.m` (or `init.wl`)

If the result was a directory `dir.mx`, it continues to look for

- `dir.mx/$SystemID/dir.mx` (insert the value of [`$SystemID`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$SystemID.html))

This is useful because `.mx` files are not compatible across different platforms.

---

`FindFile["foo"]`, where `foo` is not a context,

- Looks on `$Path` for `foo`.

If the result is a directory, then it continues to look for

- `foo/$SystemID/foo`

This is useful with [`Install`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Install.html), when we need a separate executable for each `$SystemID`, but we want to be able to use the same name to refer to them on any platform.

---

#### Notes

The context of a package, i.e. the context given in `BeginPackage` that will contain the public package symbols, *does not play any role in how `FindFile` resolves a context name to a file path*.

However, `Needs` is different from `Get` in that it expects the context passed to it to appear in [`$Packages`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%24Packages.html) after the package has been loaded. This is why one needs to use [`BeginPackage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BeginPackage.html) and not merely [`Begin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Begin.html) when writing a package.  `BeginPackage` will permanently add that context both to `$ContextPath` and `$Packages`. `Needs` uses `$Packages` to determine if a package has already been loaded and avoid double-loading.

In short, the *file names* and the *context* of a package don't strictly need to be the same.  But if they aren't, Mathematica will sometimes get confused.

The rules described above explain why the standard application directory structure is as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124599/12).  There is nothing strictly enforcing this particular structure, but the system is designed in a way that it expects to find this structure in any package.

---

Some interesting undocumented variables:

- `` Internal`$PackageDependencies `` is updated by `BeginPackage` based on its second argument
- `$LoadedFiles` is updated by `Get`.  To get a more useful list, use `Select[$LoadedFiles, Not@StringStartsQ[#, $InstallationDirectory] &]`

Comment: Feel free to edit this post to add or correct details.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not that Mathematica can not find the file, which it would indicate with another message. The problem is that `Needs` insists in your package to create the context it loads and put it onto `$Packages`.

To achieve that you need `` BeginPackage["foo`"] `` and the corresponding `EndPackage` in that file. Using that standard idiom will also make it possible to use the function name without the full context. That will of course also become a more minimal solution for the OPs problem.

From your comment I understand that you want to load the package but not have the package context in `$ContextPath`. The answer of *Simoon Rochester* shows you several ways to achieve that. Here are some more:

use `Needs` as usual, but remove the package name from `$ContextPath` afterwards:

```
Needs["foo`"]; $ContextPath = DeleteCases[$ContextPath,"foo`"]
```

the following will do the same and is somewhat more elegant and in some senses more reliable:

```
Block[{$ContextPath=$ContextPath},Needs["foo`"]]
```

but using `Block` in that way might have additional subtleties in specific situations.

Another thing you can do is to use two contexts, one for loading, the other one as the namespace of your symbols. If you put the following into file loadfoo.m:

```
BeginPackage["loadfoo`"];
EndPackage[];
Begin["foo`"];
hello = Function[{}, Print["Hello world!"]];
End[];
```

then

```
Needs["loadfoo`"]
```

will load with no error or warning messages and put `` "loadfoo`" `` onto `$ContextPath` but with no symbols in it. That file will also define `` foo`hello `` which you can use as you seem to intend.

**EDIT** *jkuczm* has silently changed a note given above which originally read that `Needs` expect the context to be added to `$ContextPath` to the more correct statement that it wants the context to be added to `$Packages`. Actually that is **all** that `Needs` really checks, a fact that I was not aware of as the pair of `BeginPackage` and `EndPackage` do more than that and the message that `Needs` just states that it wants the context to be created. Acutally you don't need to create any symbols in that context nor put it onto `$ContextPath` as I always assumed. So a file "test.m" anywhere in `$Path` will be loaded with no error messages by `Needs` if it contains just this:

```
Unprotect[$Packages];
AppendTo[$Packages,"test`"];
Protect[$Packages];
```

Using that idea, putting the following into a file "foo.m" should also solve the OPs problem without any special care by the user who loads and without adding an empty context to `$ContextPath`:

```
Unprotect[$Packages];
AppendTo[$Packages,"foo`"];
Protect[$Packages];
Begin["foo`"];
hello = Function[{}, Print["Hello world!"]];
End[];
```

which has the advantage that it can be loaded with just `` Needs["foo`"] `` and avoids any unnecessary side effects.

Comment: "Using that standard idiom will also make it possible to use the function name without the full context...":  This is **precisely** what I want to disallow.  I want to make the use of full context **mandatory** when invoking imported functions.  Is there no way to do this?

Comment: @kjo this comment really needs to be included in the question itself as it serves to frame it.

Comment: @jkuczm: I just added another solution based on your edit. I have never realized that in all these years :-). I have also made this a community wiki so feel free to add or correct more...

Answer (score 4):

You've got more than one question here, but I'm not sure which problem you're really trying to solve.

- From the title: "How does `` Needs["foo`"] `` find the file that defines context `` foo` ``?"

`Needs` looks for a file in the `$Path` or in the current working directory named `foo.m` or `foo.wl`. (As a complication, there is also [a list of Paclet directories that it looks in](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59127/path-hijacked-by-pacletmanager), but you can ignore that if you're not using `PacletInfo.m` files. The paclet files can be used to register packages where the file names don't correspond to the contexts, however, which may address one of your other questions.)

- What else must I put in ./client.m, besides `` Needs["foo`"] ``, so that the expression `` foo`hello[] `` evaluates properly?

You don't need to put anything else. `` foo`hello[] `` should already be evaluating properly with what you have (assuming `foo.m` has been found on the `$Path`). The warning message that you get when you evaluate `Needs` doesn't affect that.

Likewise for the question from your comment about making the the use of full context manditory -- you have already done that, by using `Begin` instead of `BeginPackage`, so that the context `` foo` `` is not added to the `$Contexts` variable.

If it is the warning message that is primarily concerning you, the best approach is to use `` Get["foo`"] `` rather than `Needs`, since `Needs` is set up to expect the context to be registered, while `Get` doesn't care.

If you want to use `Needs` because you only want to load `foo.m` once in the session, you could instead use the `Once` function (new in version 11):  `` Once[Get["foo`"]] ``. Or you could just use `` Quiet[Needs["foo`"]] `` or `Off[Needs::nocont]` to suppress the warning message.