# Complete list of values for \$SystemID, \$OperatingSystem

Tags: documentation, system-variables

The documentation lists some "typical values", but it leaves out some; e.g. `"Windows-x86-64"`. Also, if the main difference between the two variables is that `$OperatingSystem` doesn't distinguish between versions of the same operating system, under what circumstances will `$SystemID` return plain `"Windows"`?

Comment: There is no reliable *complete* list of values because Mathematica could always be released for one more platform (as it has been released for Raspberry Pi and recently a beta for iPad).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The purpose of `$OperatingSystem`** is to check what general OS you are on.  You would check `$OperaingSystem` for tasks such as determining whether to extract a system setting from the registry (Windows only) or elsewhere, whether to run `which.exe` or `where` to find the location of an executable, whether to use `/` or `\` as a path separator (although for this we have `$PathnameSeparator`), etc.

**The purpose of `$SystemID`** is to distinguish between incompatible system types. Thus `$SystemID` will be different not only for operating systems, but also for processor types or for different OS [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s.  You would check `$SystemID` before deciding which LibraryLink library to load, which MathLink executable to `Install`, which [MX](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MX.html) file to load, etc., as all these are architecture dependent, and will not be compatible between a 32 and 64 bit version of the same operating system, or between different processor types (e.g. ARM vs x86). In fact, Mathematica already looks for certain files (shared libraries, MX files) [in locations that depend on `$SystemID`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133275/12).

In the practical use cases I can think of you will not need to check for a specific value of `$SystemID` unless you have access to that system.  For example, if you don't have access to that system, you can't create MX files for it, or compile executables or shared libraries for it.

---

Here is a list of currently used `$SystemID`s that I could gather. I am not 100% certain that all these are correct. These are gathered from various places.

- Windows, 32-bit, Intel: `Windows`
- Windows, 64-bit, Intel: `Windows-x86-64`
- OS X, 64-bit, Intel: `MacOSX-x86-64`
- OS X, 32-bit, Intel: `MacOSX-x86`. There are no 32-bit Intel versions of M for OS X at this moment.
- OS X, PowerPC: `MacOSX`. Not in use anymore—Apple stopped using PowerPC processors in 2006.
- OS X, ARM (Apple Silicon): `MacOSX-ARM64`
- Linux, 32-bit, Intel: `Linux`
- Linux, 64-bit, Intel: `Linux-x86-64`
- Linux, 32-bit, Raspberry Pi: `Linux-ARM`

Comment: `"MacOSX"` would be the `$SystemID` for the PowerPC architecture, and `"MacOSX-x86"` for 32-bit Intel OS X. Of course, both of them are not currently used.

Comment: @ilian What is returned by `$SystemID` for Mathematica 12.3.1 running on Mac OS with Apple Silicon?  Thanks.

Comment: It should be "MacOSX-ARM64"