# How to find all package we can Needs

Tags: packages

We can encounter that interesting package sometimes,like `` GUIKit` ``,but I don't know how to find those.I can found that package which has been default loaded

```
Union[Select[GeneralUtilities`SymbolNameContext /@ 
   GeneralUtilities`ExtendedNames[All], StringCount[#, "`"] == 1 &]]
```

> `` {Algebra`,AlphaIntegration`,Assumptions`,AssumptionsDump`,Audio`,AugmentedData`,BinningUtilities`,BoxForm`,BoxFormat`,BrowserCategoryLoad`,Calendar`,CCodeGenerator`,CCompilerDriver`,Charting`,Clipboard`,CloudObject`,CloudSystem`,Compile`,Compiler`,ComplexAnalysis`,Conditional`,ConsoleWindow`,Control`,ControlSystems`,Conversion`,CUDAInformation`,Data`,Database`,DatabaseLink`,DataPaclets`,Dataset`,DateAndTime`,Debug`,Debugger`,Deconvolve`,Developer`,...} ``

But It's don't include `` GUIKit` ``.So how to find those package which have not been default loaded but exist in my local disk?

Comment: You can find source code of many packages if you evaluate `SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns"}]` . In the subfolder "Packages" there is also GUIKit package.

Comment: @Pinti Oh,I find that,so this folder contain all package we can `Needs`?

Comment: I think `Needs` looks for packages in all folders listed in `$Path`.

Comment: @Pinti Thanks for your explanation,I thinks if you compose it for read,I will accepted that.

Comment: at least closely related: [**133242**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133242/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Needs` by default searches for packages in folders listed in `$Path`.

One of the elements of `$Path` is also `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns"}]` where you can find source code of many additional packages that come with Mathematica but are not part of `System` context.