# Why do I have to run the package to make the function available?

Tags: packages

I made the following package file :

```
BeginPackage["thermotoolpackage`"]

LLog[x_] := If[x != 0, Log[x], 0]

H2[x_] := (-x)*LLog[x] - (1 - x)*LLog[1 - x]

InvH2BrancheDroite[x_] := 1 - InverseFunction[H2][x]
EntropyMat[M_] := Module[{eigenValues, entropy},
  eigenValues = Eigenvalues[M];
  entropy = -Sum[
     If[eigenValues[[i]] != 0, eigenValues[[i]]*Log[eigenValues[[i]]],
       0], {i, Length[eigenValues]}]
  ]
VectToDensityMat[v_] := Module[{rho},
  rho = Array[v[[#1]]*Conjugate[v[[#2]]] &, {Length[v], Length[v]}]
  ]

test[x_] := x + 1
EndPackage[]
```

**The cell of this package is parametrised as "initialization cell".**

In my code, I first load the package :

```
<< thermopackage`
```

But all functions excepted test are recognized. If I do test[2] it does not recognize it a a function (whereas LLog, H2 etc are recognized).

I actually just reopened this old package I made in the past and wanted to add functions (like the example test), and the recent functions I added to my package aren't recognized, and I don't get why.

They are only recognized if I first open the package and run it.

How to make it work ? Mathematica seems again very complicated for a very basic task.

Comment: Mathematica does not need to be complicated. What is in you *actual* package file? You do not say it explciitly, but it seems that you are saving a notebook as a package, and only show us what  you see in the notebook. There is often no reason to do this, as package files can be edited as if they were a notebook. Almost certainly, your package file does not contain what you believe it does.

Comment: @Szabolcs hmmm I'm not sure to totally get what you mean, but my package is saved as a .wl file (when I open it with mathematica there is the icon "run package" for example that doesn't shows up for an usual notebook).

Comment: OK, that clears up one bit, but I still don't understand fully: are you saying that ``<< thermopackage` `` and pressing Run Package have different effects?  Then ``<< thermopackage` `` does not load the file you think it is loading. Evaluate ``FindFile["thermopackage`"]`` to see what it loads.

Comment: @Szabolcs you are right. It is totally my mistake I loaded another file actually. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use `Get["/path/to/file"]` to load a specific file. Speaking of complicated things, file lookup _is_ complicated. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133275/12  I think it's a better idea to only use the ``Get["context`"]`` syntax with packages that are properly installed in a standard location (such as `$UserBaseDirctory/Applications`).

Answer (score 2):

I put your code in a initialization cell and saved it to my desktop as `thermopkg.wl`. I  quit my local and restarted it fresh notebook. I load your package with

```
Needs["thermotoolpackage`", FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "thermopkg.wl"}]]
```

I then evaluated

```
?? test
```

and got

[image: into.png]

So it looked like `test` was loaded OK, and I tried

```
test[42]
```

> `43`

I infer from this that there nothing intrinsically wrong with your pacakage and your problems problems reside from trying to load the package into a notebook that had conflicting symbols defined.

BTW, it is better to write packages in the package editor that in a notebook. You can do that by opening a new package editor window with File > New > Package.

Comment: When did the package editor get introduced?

Comment: @CATrevillian. I really don't know. I believe Its current form goes back to V11.0..

Comment: thank you! I ask because I had to piece together a custom packager (from older code not updated in a few versions) in a notebook that autowrites to .m upon saving. I know that is older and .wl is newer, but I wasn’t able to have it function at the time. Maybe now I’ll use this editor! :)