# Register "initialization code" to run on any newly started parallel kernel

Tags: parallelization, initialization

Is it possible to register a some "initialization code" to be run on any newly started parallel kernel?

This would be similar to how [`ParallelNeeds`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelNeeds.html) registers a package to be loaded right away when a new kernel is started, or how [`DistributeDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributeDefinitions.html) and [`SetSharedVariable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSharedVariable.html)/[`SetSharedFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSharedFunction.html) take effect immediately on a newly launched subkernel.

**Why do I need this?**

Mainly to make sure that certain global settings are set. Examples: `$Path`, `$Assumptions`, `$MaxExtraPrecision`, etc.  The biggest reason is really `$Path`.

Note that kernels may get launched automatically, even during ongoing computations. When a kernel dies unexpectedly, it will be re-launched.

**Related:**

- [Package found with `Needs`, but not with `ParallelNeeds`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11595/12)
- [How to use the Autoload directory?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114957/12)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found two ways to do this.  Both are undocumented, so all usual caveats apply.

#### `` Parallel`Developer`$InitCode ``

This can be done using `` Parallel`Developer`$InitCode ``.  While undocumented, this does appear fairly stable.

First trigger loading the parallel tools:

```
Parallelize;

?Parallel`Developer`$InitCode
```

> `ReleaseHold[$InitCode]` is run on every new subkernel for user initialization.

Just set

```
Parallel`Developer`$InitCode = Hold[your; code; here]
```

One problem with this is that it will be run only *after* packages registered by `ParallelNeeds` are loaded. Thus it cannot be used to set the `$Path`.

#### `` Parallel`Protected`AddInitCode ``

The following is a hack messing with the internals of the parallel tools package.  *Use at your own risk.*  The advantage is that it can be used to set `$Path`, to be used with `ParallelNeeds`.

```
Parallelize; (* trigger loading *)

?Parallel`Protected`AddInitCode
```

> `AddInitCode[code]` sends code to running subkernels and uses `AppendInitCode` to remember it.

```
?Parallel`Protected`AppendInitCode
```

> `AppendInitCode[code]` is for load-time setup of init code.

Register code to be run at kernel startup like this:

```
Parallel`Protected`AddInitCode[
 Parallel`Client`HoldCompound[your; code; here],
 True (* permanent *)
]
```

The second argument controls whether this init code should survive `` Parallel`Developer`ClearKernels[] ``.  This argument can be omitted and defaults to `False`.

This is the same mechanism that `ParallelNeeds` uses.  Make sure to register the `$Path` change *before* evaluating `ParallelNeeds`.

[`SetSharedVariable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSharedVariable.html)/[`SetSharedFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSharedFunction.html) also make use of `AddInitCode`.

These initialization code will be registered in the following variables:

```
Parallel`Kernels`Private`$clientCode
Parallel`Kernels`Private`$clientOriginalCode
```

`$clientOriginalCode` contains code set to persist even after `ClearKernels[]`. `$clientCode` contains all init code, both persistent and not.