# Error message when calling Parallelize

Tags: warning-messages, parallelization

I have some initialization code that I would like to run on any newly started kernel, and, following [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131856/register-initialization-code-to-run-on-any-newly-started-parallel-kernel), my code starts with a call to `Parallelize;` on its own, which as I understand it functions to trigger the loading of the Parallel package components.

This was working just fine yesterday, but as of today it returns an error message:

```
Image::imgarray: The specified argument {{{255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,<<100>>},{255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,<<100>>},<<47>>,{255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
 255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,<<100>>},<<43>>},{<<1>>}}   
 should be an array of rank 2 or 3 with machine-sized numbers. >>
```

> [image]

I imagine this is not a big deal, but I'm still a bit worried about it and if it's fixable I would like to do that. I know that the code in the answer I referenced is undocumented and therefore caveat-worthy, but this behaviour also appears with things as innocuous as

```
ParallelTable[
 n
 , {n, 1, 20}]
```

and that definitely shouldn't be happening, right?

In case it's necessary, I'm running v10.0.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014). I had hoped this would go away after a system restart but it persists.

Comment: I have version 10.0 for Windows (64 bits) and the *innocuous* code gives no error.

Comment: Please always use three-digit version numbers. I assume this is 10.0.2?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, it's 10.0.2

Comment: It's strange and probably something specific to your configuration. I would try to reset Mathematica (i.e. clean up the contents of `~/.Mathematica` and remove what I don't need—or rather remove everything except the license, and put back any packages/init files one by one).

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have the `SE-Tools` package installed?