# init.m in Autoload directory is not read by parallel kernels in M11.2

Tags: parallelization, initialization

Parallel kernels are not reading the `init.m` files in `$UserBaseDirectory/Autoload` since version 11.2.  The master kernel reads it fine.  In earlier versions of Mathematica parallel kernels read these `init.m` files.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have v9.0 here, but in 10.0 and later `init.m` is definitely not evaluated on parallel kernels.

Comment: I believe it worked from `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "Autoload", "Kernel", 
  "init.m"}]` in 11.0 and 11.1.  The key could be the `Autoload` part.  I realise this is a non-standard (or very old) location but it worked, up until 11.2.

Comment: I think that's an incorrect use of the Autoload directory. It should contain packages, not `Kernel/init.m`.  A package itself may (and should) contain a `Kernel/init.m`.  This `init.m` has nothing to do with `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m`—it's not an alternative for it.  When you put `Kernel/init.m` in Autoload it considered that a package.

Comment: All that said, it does appear that subkernels stopped loading autoload packages in 11.2, so the solution I suggested no longer works. I think I'll ask support about this because I don't know any other reasonable way to run initialization code on subkernels.

Comment: The `sysinit.m` file used to have a check for the `-noinit` option, which would control if `Kernel/init.m` should load.  It also contained the code to load Autoload stuff (unconditionally).  None of this is present in `sysinit.m` anymore in 11.2. These files must be loading by another mechanism.

Comment: Could you please edit the question to explain that what has changed is not how `$(User)BaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m` is read, but how `Autoload` packages are read?

Comment: @Szabolcs Actually I'm not sure how `Autoload` works, and the documentation isn't great.  I tried putting the init.m in `C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Autoload` but it didn't work, (not even for the main kernel).  I'll try again later.

Comment: I think what happens is that *any* file named `init.m` within Autload will be loaded, but I haven't had time to look at it in detail yet.  I found the file where the loading code was moved to. It's not `sysinit.m` but `Initialization....m`, forgot the exact name.

Comment: I edited the question to avoid confusion, as it was making incorrect claims. `$(User)BaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m` has *never* been read by the parallel kernels.  What changed in 11.2 is that now `init.m` files *in various locations* within the `Autoload` directory also don't load on parallel kernels.

Answer (score 4):

This works

```
Parallel`Developer`$InitCode=Hold[Get[FileNameJoin[{$BaseDirectory,"Kernel","init.m"}]]]
```

c/o 
[Register "initialization code" to run on any newly started parallel kernel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131856/register-initialization-code-to-run-on-any-newly-started-parallel-kernel)

However, it is undocumented.