# Parallelization option gives Import error for Package files

Tags: import, parallelization, packages

I have an issue when trying to use parallelization when loading a stand-alone Package. To simplify the question I have a few scenarios:

1. The first scenario, with single-kernel evaluation, works fine:

   ```
   Needs["MyPackage`"] then run   
   Map[function_call_from_package, {data}]
   ```
2. Now on to multiple kernels and parallel evalution:

   ```
   ParallelNeeds["MyPackage`"]
   ParallelMap[function_call_from_package, {data},  DistributedContexts -> {"MyPackage`", "Global`"}]
   ```

   **this fails**, reporting "Cannot open MyPackage`"
3. I also tried tips from a previous discussion 
   ([Package found with `Needs`, but not with `ParallelNeeds`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11595/package-found-with-needs-but-not-with-parallelneeds)). This reports "Import::nffil: File not found during Import"

   It's trying to load stuff from ".m" files which have generic paths

   "profilePath"-> "/Package/

   because this is later joined as

   ```
   Import[StringJoin[Directory[],OptionValue["profilePath"]],"Table"];
   ```
4. If I put absolute paths to "profilePath" -> "Absolute paths", it works.

The latter is an ugly solution, so I would appreciate your help on this.