# How can I set global computation options ($MaxPiecewiseCases) for parallel kernels?

Tags: parallelization

I'm trying to do a calculation in parallel that requires setting $MaxPiecewiseCases. How can I do this? This small test case doesn't work for me:

```
$MaxPiecewiseCases = 1000;
Print[$MaxPiecewiseCases];
ParallelEvaluate[$MaxPiecewiseCases = 500; Print[$MaxPiecewiseCases]];
```

Instead the output is:

```
During evaluation of In[118]:= 1000
(kernel 7) 100
(kernel 8) 100
(kernel 9) 100
...
```

Comment: I get `500` from the parallel kernels in V9.0.1, V8.0.4 (Mac OSX).

Comment: Hummm, If I restart Mathematica, and run the setup before any other calculations, it works. Should have thought of that.

Comment: Note that if any of the parallel kernels crashes and is (automatically or otherwise) restarted, this setting will be lost. Whether or not that is a problem for you depends on the application, obviously, but if it is--it's better to make the setting in `$InitCode` rather than explicitly.

Comment: @OleksandrR. [``Parallel`Developer`$InitCode``](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7107/using-launchkernels-to-launch-kernels-with-lower-priorities/7117#7117) is hard to find within *Mathematica*.