# How to ensure that a package is always loaded on startup, even in parallel kernels?

Tags: packages, parallelization, kernel-startup, initialization

Is there a robust way to ensure that a package is always loaded on startup, even in parallel kernels?

Parallel kernels do not read `Kernel/init.m`.

Comment: Don't know if they answer your question, but have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11602/9490) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7117/9490)?

Comment: @JasonB I'm on the way to the solution with `Autoload`, but I haven't figured out all the details yet.

Answer (score 8):

The `Autoload` mechanism can be used for this.  Place the package in `$UserBaseDirectory/Autoload` or `$BaseDirectory/Autoload`.

However, the package must follow the standard structure, and must have a `Kernel/init.m` file, [otherwise it won't get loaded](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114957/12).

Also keep in mind that auto-loading of packages happens [only after](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110243/handling-kernel-start-what-is-a-full-initialization-stack-and-what-place-the-au) `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m` was loaded (on the main kernel; subkernels don't load the standard kernel `init.m` because [they are launched with `-noinit`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11595/12)).