# Problem with autoloading packages in Parallel kernels on 11.2

Tags: parallelization, kernel-startup, version-11.2

After migrating to a new machine (running Mathematica 11.2 on Linux), I am experience a problem with packages in the autoload directory not loading when I launch parallel kernels.

The setup I use is as follows (I've used this before on previous Mathematica versions, where it worked perfectly.)

- In  `\$UserBaseDirectory/Autoload/AddPath` there is a single file `init.m`.
- This file contains a single line: `AppendTo[\$Path,(some directory)]`

This works perfectly when launch a main kernel, adding the necessary directory to my `$Path`. However, the path is *not* added when launching parallel kernels using `LaunchKernels[]`. This is weird since this worked on other machines (running earlier versions). Has something changed in this new version? Alternative, is there something the system administrator (not me in this case) could have messed up when setting op Mathematica?

Comment: [You need `Autoload/AddPath/Kernel/init.m`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114955/5478) does it work now?

Comment: I tried both, neither works.

Comment: Either way this question is a duplicate, do you agree? So I'd mark it as such and add a comment under linked answer about problems you are experiencing.

Comment: It is not a duplicate in the sense that the specific question is whether something changed in recent versions. A comment also really won't provide sufficient space to explain the context of the problem, I am experiencing.

Comment: Indeed, this no longer works in 11.2.  I wrote to Wolfram Support a while ago, and they confirmed the behaviour, but they have not yet responded about whether this change was intentional or a "bug".  There is a duplicate of your question on this site, but I need to find it.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for help

Comment: The only workarounds I know of are the methods I described here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131858/12

Comment: @Szabolcs would be good to think how to consolidate all those topics about Autoload.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks that indeed covered what I needed to know. Very frustrating change in Mathematica though.

Comment: The bug is still present in 11.3. I just updated from 11.1 to 11.3 a few days ago, and all my codes which relied on parallel evaluation of tables, stopped working, since all my definitions are inside some custom packages I created. Any news about this? It is quite annoying that a change of version breaks completely one's working code.